# Inverting DC voltage

Tags: voltage, dc, negative, inverting

I want to invert a DC voltage of 12V to -12V in the simplest way possible, since this circuit will be used in a bigger rad-hard project. I cannot use directly a DC/DC converter or any other ICs, but the objective is to use a simple topology.
I tried to use a "negative charge pump" topology (https://rf5.github.io/2019/09/10/bjt-charge-pump.html), but seems to not work fine: the circuit is "suffering" the changing of the load in output, so sometimes I was getting -8V instead of -12V.

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: What's your problem with the charge pump? How much current do you need?

Comment: The charge pump that I tried to use to invert the voltage was "suffering" the changing of the load in output, so sometimes I was getting -8V instead of -12V.
As current, I would like to have 10 mA.

Comment: It sounds like your load draws more current than the charge pump can provide, then. How much current does your load need? Also, what counts as a "DC/DC converter" that you cannot use? Because I would consider a charge pump a type of DC-DC converter.

Comment: As DC/DC I mean no ICs, I need a simple topology. 
The load current should be between 10mA and 20mA.

Comment: How did you even do a charge pump with no ICs‽

Comment: I was referring to this design, but probably there can be sth better: https://rf5.github.io/2019/09/10/bjt-charge-pump.html

Comment: What's the issue with ICs? I can point you to an IC that will do what you need with very little hassle, but doing this all in discrete components is not going to be what I would call a simple topology.

Comment: I know, the problem is that I need to avoid ICs for rad-hard purposes.

Comment: Ah, I see. That does complicate matters. What *do* you have access to? The design you linked uses an external clock signal, so you presumably have a clock source. How regulated does the output need to be? You *could* just use a push-pull driver and a rad-hard linear regulator on the other side of the transformer.

Comment: Can't use a rad-hard linear regulator. Can't use a transformer. I need a simple topology as I mentioned before. That's why in the beginning I was thinking to use a "negative charge pump", but does not seem to suit properly for this purpose.

Comment: Why can't you use a transformer or a linear regulator? Transformers are passives, and I'm sure rad-hard linear regulators exist. How well regulated does the output need to be? You can skip the regulator if you can tolerate poor output regulation.

Comment: I cannot use the transformer because I need to use as much space as I can on the PCB, and the transformer may occupy too much space.

Comment: @FrancescoPoziello, you need to put all the missing information (you added in the comments) into your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Wasn’t there a near identical question to this one about one week ago?

Comment: Please post complete schematic of your charge pump and oscillogram of it with and without load.

Comment: If you use a bigger caps the voltage will not fall so extremelly.

Answer (score 2):

Since you indicate that you have a clock available to you, this is the simplest topology I can think of:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUV5Ks.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a flyback converter with a zener diode as an output regulator. You may need to add a snubber on the input side of the transformer to protect M1.

For the low currents you need, the transformer doesn't have to be very large. You might be able to use a Coilcraft LPD3015, for instance, which is only 3 mm by 3 mm.

This is not the most efficient design. If you can implement feedback control, you can make this more efficient by regulating from the input side instead of using a linear post-regulator (the zener diode). If you can't implement feedback control, you can reduce the power wasted in the zener by using a simple zener+resistor+BJT linear regulator--it'll still be inefficient due to being linear, but the quiescent current will be lower.

It is, however, the simplest topology I can think of for producing a regulated -12 V from a +12 V input.

Comment: @greybeard I did, but I also noted their reason for doing so was that the transformer is too big. As such, I pointed out a specific coupled inductor that might be suitable that is probably smaller than that 1 mF capacitor they had in the capacitive charge pump schematic.